# NDsolve with discontinuous non-numeric PDE coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I want to solve the heat diffusion equation with variable thermal conductivity. So I have the following code

```
Clear["Global'*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]];
k[x_, y_] := piecewise[{{10, x^2 + y^2 <= 2}, {5, x^2 + y^2 > 2}}];

gT = Grad[w[x, y], {x, y}];
tC = {{k, 0}, {0, k}};
pde = Div[tC.gT, {x, y}];


sol = First@NDSolve[{pde == 0,
 DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 100, y == 0],
 DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 400, y == 10],
 DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, x == 0],
 DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, x == 10]},
{w}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

However I get this error

```
The PDE coefficient {{k,0},{0,k}} does not evaluate to a numeric \
matrix of dimensions {2,2}.
```

And I have not been able to figure out why this occurs and I've already looked at the following which didn't help.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html
[NDSolve for axisymmetric problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78611/ndsolve-for-axisymmetric-problem)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Also, as another problem I'm experiencing, is that if I take away the First@ in First@NDsolve. I get the following errors.

```
0.000714286 cannot be used as a variable
0.000714286 cannot be used as a variable
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: `k` and `k[x,y]` are different things as far as _Mathematica_ is concerned.  Have you tried replacing the former with the latter in your definition for `tC`?

Comment: If I do that I get `The PDE coefficient {{piecewise[{{10,x^2+y^2<=2},{5,x^2+y^2>2}}],0},{0,\
piecewise[{{10,x^2+y^2<=2},{5,x^2+y^2>2}}]}} does not evaluate to a \
numeric matrix of dimensions {2,2}.` and `0.0007142857142857143 is not a valid variable`

Comment: `Piecewise` should be capitalized, like all built-in _Mathematica_ functions.

Comment: There's one more error in your code (it's not an uncommon error for Mathematica newbies, and completely understandable.)  See my full answer below.

Comment: @MonkSphere The plot command should be `ContourPlot[w[x, y] /. sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`.  The solution `sol` is a replacement rule for `w`.  (Type `sol` to see.)  BTW, you can set up the mesh with an interior boundary that matches the discontinuity in `k`.  See the "Element Mesh Creation" tutorial.  (In this example, the discontinuity is practically insignificant, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there are three main errors:

1. `k` and `k[x, y]` are not the same thing in Mathematica.
2. `Piecewise` should be capitalized.
3. `NDSolve` returns a list of "rules" for the various solutions of the equations, which need to be "applied" (using `/.`) to be plotted.  Alternately, if you know that there's only going to be one solution of the equations, you can use `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve`, which returns the function itself rather than the rules.

Corrected code and results:

```
Clear["Global'*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]];
k[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{10, x^2 + y^2 <= 2}, {5, x^2 + y^2 > 2}}];

gT = Grad[w[x, y], {x, y}];
tC = {{k[x, y], 0}, {0, k[x, y]}};
pde = Div[tC.gT, {x, y}];


sol = First@NDSolve[{pde == 0,
  DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 100, y == 0],
  DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 400, y == 10],
  DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, x == 0],
  DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, x == 10]},
  {w}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

ContourPlot[w[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Alternately,

```
sol = First@NDSolveValue[{pde == 0, ...

ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

gives the same results.